# junit 5 compile as module

Tags: java, module, junit5

I have a question about junit.jupiter. Is it useful to compile the test as module? Something like that?

```
module usecases {
  requires org.junit.jupiter.api;
}
```

When I try to compile with ant, I get the following error message:

```
[javac] error: module not found: org.opentest4j
[javac] error: module not found: org.apiguardian.api
```

I don't understand it because inside the classpath it would compile without problems but in the module-path not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both modules and also `org.junit.platform.commons` are required to satisfy the declarations of [`org.junit.jupiter.api`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/master/junit-jupiter-api/src/module/org.junit.jupiter.api/module-info.java). See this snippet of the module descriptor:

```
/**
 * Defines JUnit Jupiter API for writing tests.
 */
module org.junit.jupiter.api {
    requires transitive org.apiguardian.api;
    requires transitive org.junit.platform.commons;
    requires transitive org.opentest4j;

    exports org.junit.jupiter.api;
...
}
```

That's why you have to configure your build tool to also provide at least those three modules.

IIRC, the default "JUnit 5" integration of Ant makes use the non-modular `junit-platform-console-standalone` artifact. Its JAR does contain all required normal classes but no `module-info.class` files. Therefore, compiling and running on the classpath works out-of-the-box.

More and recent details for using the "JUnitLauncher Task" can be found here: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitlauncher.html

Comment: Just one another question... I need the name of the module junit-platform-console-standalone-1.5.2.jar. The real name is in the module-info.java. How can I get the name?